# How to prove Eigenvalues of conductivity operator are real?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given that $\Omega$ be bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Assume that the divergence theorem is applicable to $\Omega$.

Let $\gamma(x)$ be real valued $C^{\infty}$ and all of whose derivatives are bounded. Suppose that $\lambda\ne 0\in \mathbb C$ and for $\phi\in C^2(\bar \Omega)$.$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\nabla\cdot[\gamma(x)\nabla\phi(x)]=\lambda\phi(x) &\forall x\in \Omega \\ 
 \phi(x)=0&x\in \partial \Omega 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$\lambda $ is eigenvalue of operator. How to prove it is real ?

Conductivity operator is $u\to \nabla\cdot [\gamma(x)\nabla u] $

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove this the same way we prove that a Hermitian matrix's eigenvalues are real. Define the inner product
\begin{equation}
\left<\phi,\psi\right> = \int_{\Omega}\phi\overline{\psi}~d\mathsf{V},
\end{equation}
where the overline indicates complex conjugation. Let $L$ be the operator in question, and let $\phi$ be an eigenfunction of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Note that since $L\phi = \lambda\phi$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left<L\phi,\phi\right> &=~ \left<\lambda\phi,\phi\right>\\
&=~ \lambda\left<\phi,\phi\right>\\
&=~ \lambda\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert_{L^2{\Omega}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left<\phi,L\phi\right> &=~ \left<\phi,\lambda\phi\right>\\
&=~ \overline{\lambda}\left<\phi,\phi\right>\\
&=~ \overline{\lambda}\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert_{L^2{\Omega}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If we can show that $\left<\phi,L\phi\right>$ and $\left<L\phi,\phi\right>$ are equal, then will have shown that $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$ are equal, which shows that $\lambda$ is real.

We will use the Divergence Theorem to show that $\left<\phi,L\phi\right>$ and $\left<L\phi,\phi\right>$ are equal.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&~~\left<\phi,L\phi\right> - \left<L\phi,\phi\right>\\
&=~\int_{\Omega}\left[\phi\nabla\cdot\left(\overline{\gamma}\nabla\overline{\phi}\right) - \overline{\phi}\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\phi\right)\right]d\mathsf{V}\\
&=~\int_{\Omega}\left[\phi\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right) - \overline{\phi}\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\phi\right)\right]d\mathsf{V}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
because $\gamma$ is real-valued.

Note that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\overline{\phi}\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\phi\right) &=~ \nabla\cdot\left[\overline{\phi}\gamma\nabla\phi\right] - (\nabla\overline{\phi})\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\phi\right)\\
&=~ \nabla\cdot\left[\overline{\phi}\gamma\nabla\phi\right] - \gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\cdot\nabla\phi
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\phi\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right) &=~ \nabla\cdot\left[\phi\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right] - (\nabla\phi)\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right)\\
&=~ \nabla\cdot\left[\phi\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right] - \gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\cdot\nabla\phi
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Hence
\begin{equation}
\phi\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right) - \overline{\phi}\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\phi\right)
~=~ \nabla\cdot\left[\phi\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi} - \overline{\phi}\gamma\nabla\phi\right].
\end{equation}

We can use this to simplify $\left<\phi,L\phi\right> - \left<L\phi,\phi\right>$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left<\phi,L\phi\right> - \left<L\phi,\phi\right> &=~ \int_{\Omega}\left[\phi\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi}\right) - \overline{\phi}\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla\phi\right)\right]d\mathsf{V}\\
&=~ \int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot\left[\gamma\left(\phi\gamma\nabla\overline{\phi} - \overline{\phi}\nabla\phi\right)\right]d\mathsf{V}\\
&=~ \oint_{\partial\Omega}\gamma\left(\phi\nabla\overline{\phi} - \overline{\phi}\nabla\phi\right)\cdot\mathbf{\nu}d\mathsf{S},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
by the Divergence Theorem, where $\mathbf{\nu}$ is the outward-facing unit normal vector field on $\partial\Omega$ and $d\mathsf{S}$ indicates integration with respect to the area measure on $\partial\Omega$.

Since we are considering functions that are zero-valued on $\partial\Omega$, and since each term in the integrand of the last line has either $\phi$ or $\overline{\phi}$, we see that the integral over $\partial\Omega$ is zero.

The conclusion is that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left<\phi,L\phi\right> &=& \left<L\phi,\phi\right>\\
\overline{\lambda}\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert_{L^2(\Omega)} &=& \lambda\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert_{L^2(\Omega)}\\
\overline{\lambda} &=& \lambda~~~~(\textrm{assuming}~\left\Arrowvert\phi\right\Arrowvert_{L^2(\Omega)} > 0)
\end{eqnarray}
This shows that $\lambda$ is real.